# Android - addView() doesn't work after removeAllViews()

Tags: java, android

I have a LinearLayout `ll` inside the other LinearLayout inside the ScrollView

---

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="270px"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/gifcreator_thumbs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/gifcreator_add"
            android:layout_width="250px"
            android:layout_height="125px"
            android:layout_margin="10px"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="Добавить кадр" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

---

In `onCreate` I'm running the update_frames() method:

---

```
public void update_frames(String a)
{
    Log.e("EmSy", "Updating Frame @ " + a);
    try
    {
        File f = new File(a);
        tag = ll.getChildCount();
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gifcreator_item, null);
        v.setTag(tag);
        v.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
                public boolean onLongClick(View v)
                {
                    delete_frame(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString()));
                    return true;
                }
            });

        ImageView thumb = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.gircreator_item_thumb);
        TextView desc = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.gifcreator_item_desc);

        Bitmap t = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(a);
        Bitmap t2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(t, 110, 110, false);
        thumb.setImageBitmap(t2);

        desc.setText("Кадр №" + tag);

        data.add(new GIFFrame(t, 42, a));

        ll.addView(v);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

Here's the `delete_frame` method:

---

```
public void delete_frame(int tag_for_deleting)
{
    try
    {
        ll.removeAllViews();
        data.remove(tag_for_deleting);
        temp_data = data;
        data.clear();

        for (GIFFrame gf : temp_data)
        {
            update_frames(gf.p);
            frames.notify();
        }

        temp_data.clear();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

So, before executing `delete_view` method all views has been added, but after executing that method the views aren't adding to the `ll`. My code stops on the `ll.addView(v)` line, so I have the rigth path to the file in my LogCat:

---

```
`ru.mso.gb - EmSy - Updating Frame @ /sdcard/pic.png`
```

---

Why it isn't working?

Comment: try `View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gifcreator_item, ll, true);` and remove addView line from update_frames method

Answer (score 0):

in your code, when you longpress a view, the main idea is to delete THE view, though you seem to remove all views,  `delete_frame(int tag_for_deleting)` should remove one view, not all the views, as made by this line `ll.removeAllViews();`

get the index of your view, and execute this instead

```
ll.removeViewAt(index)
```

EDIT:
After reading your code again, it looks like when you want to delete 1 single line, you delete everything and build your layout from scratch, this is `BAD`, very BAD, instead, remove the one view you want to remove by the line I posted above, and remove the one info from the arraylist, that's it

Comment: No, I need to delete ALL views to rebuild ArrayList<GIFFrame> and tags. Anyway, thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: that's not true, you can delete one item from the arraylist without affecting the rest of the data, and about your tags, they are still valid, anyway I don't see the whole point of rebuilding every time, if I'm missing something please explain so others can help

Answer (score 0):

Problem here

```
temp_data = data;
data.clear();
```

You just add new reference to data, then clear it. This means code in the loop never run.

You can do the following
replace

```
temp_data = data;
```

with

```
temp_data = new ArrayList<your type here>(data)
```